# Button Google plus zero +1, DNS issue?

Tags: google-plus

Since the 21st june all my post in my web have zero in the G+ button indicator although in Google plus all of them has many +1. For example:

Google plus post +6:
https://plus.google.com/u/0/111402624595533102497/posts/3tQoKE2juv4

Post in my web +0:
http://iphone-6.es/iphone-5s-lanzamiento-20-septiembre-espana/

But the home page gets right the +1

I have investigated what I have done and I think the issue is:
**In june I activated Cloud Flare (I had to change my DNS) and the 19th of june I switched off cloud flare and my internet provider gave me another DNS (differents to the ones I had before all this change)**

** Nowadays, the domain is in an internet provider and the hosting in a different one. I give this information in case it can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that the URL picked up by the Google+ proxies is different as a result of the changes. As far as I can tell, everything is set correctly, but if there was a URL from before that was different, you can try providing the URL explicitly in your button markup:

```
<a 
  rel="nofollow" 
  class="addthis_button_google_plusone" 
  g:plusone:size="medium"  
  href = "http://iphone-6.es/iphone-5s-lanzamiento-20-septiembre-espana/"
  onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'finpost', 'click', 'google-plus-sidebar', 0 ,true]);">
</a>
```

I tried this with your example URL and it doesn't seem to be making a difference. You might also want to check that your canonical tags have not changed because this could prevent the proxy from mapping your site back to the original link.

Upon further inspection it looks like your +1 links might not be resolving correctly.  For example, [this page](http://iphone-6.es/ios-7-iphone-ipod-touch-ipad-sin-instalacion/?icn=postslinked&ici=i5slanz20sepespana) seems to be working. You might want to try the following:

- Explicitly setting the urls (as shown above) to what the pages were resolving as before.
- Removing the canonical tag from your page to see if it resolves better.
- Identifying articles where the +1 is working and comparing where it doesn't - there is probably a pattern for the pages not matching.

Comment: I think it hasn't to do with canonical tags because if you were right, I haven't to have any problems with the new posts but I have this issue with them :( Thanks Gus!!

Comment: It's interesting that the home page is working but not other pages, I'll look further into this. When you say the home page is working do you mean that your follower count on Google+ is unchanged?

Comment: My follower count of +263 in G+ works ok. I have checked 5 minutes ago. If you need more information about the domain or hosting you can ask me. I apreciate very much your help :D

Comment: The follower count is unrelated to your +1 button count which is why it's working as expected. However... it looks to me like your +1 links on your current site are not matching the +1 links from before, I updated the answer with some suggestions.

Comment: All the post before aprox. 21st June work OK.I checked all my Wordpress and I found this "Site URL http::/iphone-6.es" I changed the 27th and I still have the same problem. Could it be that Google "thinks" that my page is still in the old DNS numbers? is there any way to notify Google the new DNS? Thanks!!